# Query later of preferred time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an appointment scheduling application that gives a user the option to select a preferred appointment time. If the preferred time is not available, we always want to show the next later appointment.

Currently I've been able to adjust the below query to return the later appointment if say the user's preferred time is 9am and there are only a 8:30am and 9:30am available. However if the preferred time is 9am and there is only an 8:30am and 10am appointment available it will return the 8:30am, because it's closer to the preferred time. I need the system to return 10am appointment, even if there was also a 10:30am appointment available. It needs to return the later but closest to the preferred time. Let me know if anyone knows how I'd need to adjust my order by clause to accomplish this. Hope that shows enough information as the entire query is very large.

```
ORDER BY ABS(DATEDIFF(n, '1/1/1900 ' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar(8), dbo.AppointmentTime, 108), 1, 5)
    , @CustomerPreferredTime)), dbo.AppointmentDateTime desc
```

Comment: Do you have a table for *possible* appointment times? Or is it something like every 30 minutes between 8:00AM and 5:00PM? Also I'm assuming you have a table of *scheduled* appointments, do they have a column for estimated duration? Or is it just assumed an appointment lasts 30 minutes?

Comment: Better question, can you provide the relevant schema information?

Answer (score 0):

Based on how the question was asked, I believe the answer from SqlZim is correct.  The condition for when an earlier appointment should be returned was not specified in the question.  I took an approach here and made the assumption you want to return an earlier appointment returned only in the event that no later appointment exists for the given day.  The solution uses the ROW_NUMBER function to sort the data, first by whether the appointment is before or after the preferred time and then by the time difference.

```
DECLARE @CustomerPreferredTime DATETIME = '6/10/17 09:00:00'

DECLARE @AppointmentDateTime TABLE
    (
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY,
        AppointmentTime DATETIME,
        Available BIT 
    )

INSERT  INTO @AppointmentDateTime
        (AppointmentTime,Available)
VALUES
        ('6/10/17 08:00:00',0),
        ('6/10/17 08:30:00',1),
        ('6/10/17 09:00:00',0),
        ('6/10/17 09:30:00',0),
        ('6/10/17 10:00:00',1),
        ('6/10/17 10:30:00',0),
        ('6/10/17 11:00:00',0),
        ('6/10/17 11:30:00',0)

SELECT TOP 1
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE    WHEN [@AppointmentDateTime].AppointmentTime >= @CustomerPreferredTime
                                        THEN 1
                                        ELSE 0
                                END DESC, ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,
                                                        @CustomerPreferredTime,
                                                        AppointmentTime))) AS ClosestAppointmentOrder,  
    [@AppointmentDateTime].AppointmentTime
FROM
    @AppointmentDateTime
WHERE
    [@AppointmentDateTime].Available = 1
    AND CONVERT(DATE,AppointmentTime) = CONVERT(DATE,@CustomerPreferredTime)
ORDER BY
    ClosestAppointmentOrder
```